# What does it mean by "recompile assemblies" in the following?| C#

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, assemblies

I faced the follwing section when reading a book about C#:

> Constants should be avoided for two important reasons: the  value must
> be known at compile time, and it must be expressible as a literal
> string, Boolean, or number value. Every reference to the const field
> is replaced  with the literal value at compile time, which will,
> therefore, not be reflected if  the value changes in a **future version**
> and you do not **recompile any assemblies**  that reference it to get the
> new value.

I have two questions now.

1- What does it mean by the highlited part "future version" above?

2- What does it mean when it says: **you do not recompile any assemblies...**? I didn't get it when I saw this part, can anyone explain that how an assembly get recompiled?

Comment: Picture a diamond dependency graph. One project is a library compiled against version `3.0.0`. A second project is a library compiled against the newer `3.0.1`. Both are included as a dependency in a 3rd project. So `3.0.1` is loaded to resolve both dependencies, though you would see a warning about that.

Comment: Can you provide more context? I'm wondering if "reflected" here is taking on more than just a simple English meaning

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you maintain a class library named `ProjectA`. You include a constant named `SomeUtil.AConstantValue` and set it to an `int` value of `1`. You release this as AssemblyVersion 1.0.0.0 and FileVersion 1.0.0.0.

```
ProjectA 1.0.0.0
```

Now let's say someone consumes your library project in `ProjectB` and uses the value of `SomeUtil.AConstantValue`. They compile their assembly, which *copies* the value 1 into the MSIL of the assembly. But that is fine at this point, because it is the same as `ProjectA`.

```
ProjectB 1.0.0.0
   |
    ---- ProjectA 1.0.0.0
```

Next, you discover that the value 1 is not a high enough value for `ProjectA`'s `SomeUtil.AConstantValue` to work correctly. So, you change the value to a 2 and release the patch with AssemblyVersion 1.0.0.0 and and FileVersion 1.1.0.0.

```
ProjectA 1.1.0.0
```

The author of `ProjectB` sees you have released a new version of `ProjectA` and decides to xCopy (fancy speak for copy and paste) the DLL to upgrade it. Since it has an AssemblyVersion of 1.0.0.0, it is binary compatible so there is no need to recompile `ProjectB`. However, since the value of 1 was copied into `ProjectB` when it was compiled, it doesn't see the new constant value.

```
ProjectB 1.0.0.0 (note the version here didn't change because it wasn't recompiled)
   |
    ---- ProjectA 1.1.0.0
```

---

If you imagine the same scenario, but use a static field instead of a constant, `ProjectB` will immediately start using the new value 2 for `SomeUtil.AConstantValue`. This is a better situation, because there won't be a difference in behavior if `ProjectB` is recompiled vs the new DLL simply copied along with `ProjectB`.

> NOTE: Generally speaking, this scenario doens't play out very often if you use NuGet because most people will recompile the application when they get the new version. The advice given is to cover cases where the DLL is unzipped from the NuGet package and copied to the bin/app folder manually or installed into the Global Assembly Cache. Any of these scenarios can be done without forcing a recompile of `ProjectB`.

### Answers

1. What does it mean by the highlited part "future version" above?

   Using the above scenario, the "future version" referred to would be FileVersion 1.1.0.0. It is considered a "future version" here, because `ProjectB` was compiled against FileVersion 1.0.0.0 (in the past).
2. What does it mean when it says: you do not recompile any assemblies...?

   In the above scenario, the author of `ProjectB` decided to copy the `ProjectA` DLL you authored into their application directory. This overwrites FileVersion 1.0.0.0. Most of the code changes that were made to `ProjectA` will immediately start being used by replacing the DLL (assembly). However, the constant value would not be utilized unless `ProjectB` is recompiled while referencing `ProjectA`.

> I didn't get it when I saw this part, can anyone explain that how an assembly get recompiled?

C# is one of many different *compiled* languages. With a compiled language the source code that is written is compiled into a format that more closely represents the machine code that the computer uses. .NET compiles down to a format called *intermediate language* (IL or MSIL), which is what usually gets deployed to the target device. In general, compiling makes the code run faster than if it is simply *interpreted* on demand.

There are compilers built into Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) such as [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), or [JetBrains Ryder](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), as well as software development kits (SDKs) that can compile on the command line (for example, the [.NET SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) which has a compile command [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)).

#### References

- [Interpreted vs. compiled languages: What's the difference?](https://www.theserverside.com/answer/Interpreted-vs-compiled-languages-Whats-the-difference)